# Suppress "Unknown global symbol" warnings in qooxdoo with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, javadoc, qooxdoo

I'm using qooxdoo in combination with the google maps API.  I'm actually using it in combination with coffeescript, but I had the same problem before I moved over to coffeescript (although I suspect coffeescript isn't helping).

When I build the project, I get a **lot** of lines like this:

```
  - Warning: myproj.App (22,50): Unknown global symbol used: 'google'
  - Warning: myproj.App (22,76): Unknown global symbol used: 'google.maps'
  - Warning: myproj.App (23,21): Unknown global symbol used: 'google'
  - Warning: myproj.App (23,47): Unknown global symbol used: 'google'
  - Warning: myproj.App (23,74): Unknown global symbol used: 'google.maps'
  - Warning: myproj.App (15,18): Unknown global symbol used: 'google.maps.LatLng'
```

I've found lots of references to `@ignoreUndefined` or `@ignore` to get rid of this, all supposed to be placed in a javadoc comment like this:

```
/**
 * @ignore(google.*)
 */
```

However, I've been unable to get this to work.  I've tried @ignoreUndefined and @ignore, with and without brackets, with `google` on it's own, with `google.` with `google*`, with `google.*`, with `google.maps.LatLng` explicitly (and all the other ones) and a few other variations.  In the coffeescript I've tried having it all in a `###` block and also in a block at the top of the file that looks like this:

```
`/**
  * @ignoreUndefined google
  */`
```

or

```
`/** @ignore(google) */`
```

(the backticks stick it straight into the javascript source unmolested).

What I really want to do is put something in `config.json` that tells it to stop complaining about google.* (this would be simpler than per-file as it will be in every file), but I can't find a way to do this.  It's starting to be a problem as I'm missing genuine mistakes amongst the pages of `Unknown global symbol used: 'google`...

Please can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

---

**Edit**

Thanks to Richard, I now have it working.  In case it's of use to anyone else, my config.json looks like this (irrelevant bits removed):

```
{
    ...

    "config-warnings" :
    {
        "job-shadowing": ["common", "lint", "source-all", "build"]
    },

    "jobs" :
    {
        "build" :
        {
            "run" :
            [
                "coffee-compile",
                "build-resources",
                "build-script",
                "build-files"
            ]
        },
        "source-all" :
        {
            "run" :
            [
                "coffee-compile",
                "source-all-script"
            ]
        },
        "common":
        {
            "lint-check": {
                "allowed-globals": [
                    "google"
                ]
            }
        },
        "lint":
        {
            "lint-check": {
                "allowed-globals": [
                    "google"
                ]
            }
        },
        "coffee-compile" :
        {
            "extend": ["common"],
            "shell" :
            {
                "command": "coffee --bare --compile --output ./source/class/myapp/ ./coffee/myapp/*.coffee"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are using qooxdoo 3.0 (the current github master branch - not yet released but very soon) which introduces the `@ignore` syntax (superseding the old `#ignore` syntax). I got it working like this in my `config.json`:

```
{
  "config-warnings" :
  {
    "job-shadowing" : ["source"],
  },

  ...

  "jobs" :
  {
    ...

    "source" :
    {   
      "lint-check" : { 
        "allowed-globals" : [ 
           "google"
        ]   
      }   
    }   
  }
}
```

Changing the `config.json` like that should also work in qooxdoo 2.1.1.

Read on:

- http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/development/api_jsdoc_at_ignore.html
- http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/development/api_jsdoc_ref.html#ignore
- http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/tool/generator/generator_config_ref.html#config-warnings
- http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/tool/migration/migration_guide.html#compiler-hints

Comment: In answer to your assumption, I was trying 3.0 and 2.1.1 to see if it made any difference.  I think I'd tried `#ignore` as well, but hadn't managed to get that to work.  Anyway, with a little tweak I've got this working.  It works okay, but then the errors appear when you run "build", so I added this to "common" AND "lint" instead of "source" and it clears all the errors.  Many many many thanks.